# best way to paginate?

Tags: java, pagination

I have a list of items, and I need to call a function with at most 30 of them each time. Here's what I'm doing:

```
final int maxItemsPerRequest = 30;
List<Item> itemsToProcess = new ArrayList<>();
for (Item item : itemsList) {
    itemsToProcess.add(item);

    if (itemsToProcess.size() % maxItemsPerRequest == 0) {
        processItem(itemsToProcess);
        itemsToProcess = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
if (itemsToProcess.size() > 0)
    processItem(itemsToProcess);
```

I feel this last check (.size() > 0) smells a bit.

Any recommendation on another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what you are trying to do.

You have a `List` of stuff with size `x`. You want to split this list into chunks of size `<= y`. Now, there is a magic [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method. This returns a **view** of a section of the list `[i, j)`.

Seems the solution should be obvious, to split the input into a `List<List<>>` of chunks use:

```
final int blockSize = 5;
List<List<String>> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i += blockSize) {
    chunks.add(items.subList(i, Math.min(i + blockSize, items.size())));
}
```

No unnecessary new lists, no strange `size > 0` at the end. Obviously you can dispatch to your processing method directly rather that accumulating into `chunks`.

A little demo in Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<String> items = Stream.generate(() -> "a").limit(47).collect(toList());
    final int blockSize = 5;
    List<List<String>> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i += blockSize) {
        chunks.add(items.subList(i, Math.min(i + blockSize, items.size())));
    }
    chunks.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a, a, a, a]
[a, a]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not yet on Java 8 then using 3rd party library might be the easiest and quickest option.

In this particular case you can benefit from Guava's [Lists.partition](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) method, which can be used as follows:

```
for (List<Foo> itemsPartition : Lists.partition(itemsList, 30)) {
    processItem(itemsPartition);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a big list and want to process it 30 items at a time, it's probably easiest to use `subList`.

```
final int BUCKET_SIZE = 30;

final List<Whatever> list = bigListOfEverything();
final int size = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += BUCKET_SIZE) {
    final List<Whatever> subList = list.subList(i, (i + BUCKET_SIZE) > size ? size : (i + BUCKET_SIZE));
    processOneBucket(subList);
}
```

If you're generating items one at a time, and you don't have a full list, it's easier to build up a list and pass it in for processing every time it reaches the expected bucket size, and once again if there's a non-empty bucket left at the end of the loop. This is what you're currently doing, it's a good approach if you don't have the full list.

Comment: This is how I'd do it, but it's probably better to use Math.min(i + BUCKET_SIZE, size) instead of an embedded if statement.